How to prevent loop in auto-switching charger using MH-CD42 and LTC4412?
I'm making UPS-like power supply using MH-CD42 lithium-ion Battery with 5V boost charging module and LTC4412 power or-ing IC chip.
I made my schematic based on the picture on google like the pictures below, using EasyEDA.

This is my schematic.

However, when I converted it to PCB, it connected MH-CD42's VIN pin and OUT(5V) pin on same 5V output line, which caused me some mild worries.

So, there are my core questions:

Is there any problem in my schematic and PCB?
How to prevent power loop if present?

Thanks for your assistance.

Is it connected? I don't see the connection you're concerned about. The layout has other problems, but I don't think a shorted net is one of them.

MOSFET control the power from two MH-CD42, and they are supplied to 5V when there is no external power. So I'm worried about if it will create power loop. By the way, what are the problems?
